# first character in the input should be letter

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an input type element that should have 5 characters starting with a letter

```
  <input mdInput #acronyme placeholder="Company" type="text" maxlength="5" minlength="5" required [value]="acronyme.value.toUpperCase()">
```

My problem is with with the starting character that should be a letter because i want to prevent the input from writing any number in the starting character

Answer (score 0):

It is an angular form, you can use model driven form and put a pattern property for the same, for an example

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z ][0-9]+"
```

this will ensure that you will have a varchar for that field, which will start with a letter.

Comment: As i know a pattern doesn't prevent you from typing in the input